# Creating a fixed element that shows up below the fold

Tags: jquery, css, position, fixed

I'm trying to create an effect similar to [this](http://whiteboard.is/index.html). The background is fixed, but changes after certain elements. I've spend a considerable amount of time on this and still have not found anything close to explaining how to do this.

Basically I was to learn how to mimic that exact effect. I want an image to be fixed, but show up below the fold. I'm sure the answer lays in jQuery, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Welcome on SO! This site is about asking and answering programming related questions, while providing the code that isn't working. Thus you should ask your question on [webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) I think. To answer you nevertheless, this type of page is called "one page layout", that should help you refine your googling (or search on SO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In very simple words you can make all the "openings" (areas where the different backgrounds show up from behind) as any other div but with

```
background-attachment:fixed
```

so if you have

[background]
[content]
[content]
[other background]
[content]
[content]
[yet another background]

it's basically

```
  <div style="background-attachment:fixed"></div>
  <div>Content</div>
  <div>Content</div>
  <div style="background-attachment:fixed"></div>
  <div>Content</div>
  <div>Content</div>
  <div style="background-attachment:fixed"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

1. Build multiple layers of backgrounds, all of them `visibility:hidden`, overlaying on top of each other in `position:fixed`.
2. Use jQuery's `.scroll()` and `.addClass()` methods to pick which background to show.

I've implemented an example in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zbn2L/

The backgrounds are solid colors, so they don't seem like they're fixed, but I don't want any copyright infringements.